# How to pause code execution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

I have datagrid, when press update button I made popup window. I want to pause update process while user fills popup window.

Comment: what is the propose of showing popup, why you need it after clicking update button and why you need to pause the update in between ... etc.. can you post markup and code. it will make us undersatnd the problem clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start the `Update` only when you have all required info, not before the user fills in data in the popup window.

the first phase would be `data capturing` from user input, then you `validate` the data are correct, valid and sufficient and only then you start the `update process` whatever it means to you (you have given too few details...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Javascript. First you should capture the event and return false. This prevents a postback. When the dialog is completely filled out and closed you can send the information to the server via as ajax call or trigger a traditional post.